# Where to download Square Wire wire-compiler-VERSION-jar-with-dependencies.jar?

Tags: proto

I want to use protobuf in Android ， and I find Square Wire. https://github.com/square/wire

In the document,  there is a command to gerate Java file.

```
% java -jar wire-compiler-VERSION-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
--proto_path=src/main/proto \
--java_out=out \
squareup/dinosaurs/dinosaur.proto \
squareup/geology/period.proto
```

I download the released zip, but there are all source code,  no Jar file.
Then ,I went to Maven Respoist, but there is no wire-compiler-VERSION-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Answer (score 1):

#### You can build it yourself with maven

Get sources, install maven and run

```
mvn package
```

You'll find wire-compiler-VERSION-jar-with-dependencies.jar in **wire/wire-compiler/target/** directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Wire's README](https://github.com/square/wire#generating-code-with-wire) has a link to download the latest [JAR](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.squareup.wire%22%20AND%20a%3A%22wire-compiler%22) from maven.org.